# Check uniqueness for a specific value in each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas.DataFrame `df` similar to this:

```py
   A0  A1   A2
0   a   a    b
1   b   b    g 
2   c   b    h 
3   d   c  NaN
```

Now there are specific values that I want to check against that DataFrame. Let's call them

```py
candidates = ["a", "b", "c", "g"]
```

For each candidate I want to check if it is unique to each column of my DataFrame (It may occur in multiple columns).
Desired output for this set of candidates would be a DataFrame with

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [
            cand,
            pd.magic(cand)
        ] for cand in candidates
    ],
    columns=["cand", "unique"]
)

>   cand  unique
  0    a    True
  1    b   False
  2    c    True
  3    g    True
```

Even better was if instead of `True` it returned the number of matches (i.e `[2, False, 2, 1]`).

I think I'll have to use [`pd.DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply), however I can't figure out how to check only for the candidates or how to bring the result for each column back together. Maybe something like `df.apply(pd.value_counts).T[cand] <= 1` is a good starting point which delivers a pd.Series with True or False for each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) to create a boolean mask corresponding to each of the candidates then use [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) to get total count of occurrences in each column, finally use [`.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) + [`.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) to check if its unique in all columns:

```
pd.DataFrame([{'cand': c, 'unique': df.eq(c).sum().lt(2).all()} for c in cand])
```

---

```
  cand  unique
0    a    True
1    b   False
2    c    True
3    g    True
```

Comment: Bonus points for you because `df.eq("some")` evaluates to True against "something", which is exactly what I was looking for. Might be a caveat for others stumbling upon your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I change yoour idea - added [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for filter by list, then compare for greater like `1`, test if at least one row and invert mask by `~`, last convert `Series` to `2 column DataFrame`:

```
df1 = ((~df.apply(pd.value_counts)
           .reindex(candidates)
           .gt(1)
           .any(axis=1))
           .rename_axis('cand')
           .reset_index(name='unique'))
print (df1)
  cand  unique
0    a    True
1    b   False
2    c    True
3    g    True
```

Comment: While your solution works and delivers the desired results I accepted Shubham's answer because it fits nicer with the code I already had in place. It's a nice idea though to basically first search for the values not unique and invert that result.